# Iterative methods for solving a linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

There are several methods known for solving a linear equation system Ax = b 
 (like Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel) by iterating

$x_{n+1}=Mx_n+c$ with a matrix M, for which some norm is smaller than 1.
 But what can be done if we have an arbitary matrix A with no special properties
 (not symmetric and not diagonaldominant) ? Must the numerical gauss-algorithm
 be used, or is there a fix-point-iteration converging in any case ?

Comment: I don't know if it may interest you, but take a look at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconjugate_gradient_method

Comment: I did not quite get it. Is this an iterative method ?

Comment: It is a generalization of the conjgate gradient method, which *technically* is a direct method because it converges to the solution in at most $n$ steps (where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix). On the other hand is often implemented as an iterative method. (It also feel like one, because you are iterating a simple procedure $n$ times)

Comment: Krylov methods like GMRES, FOM, BiCG, CGS, BiCGStab, QMR, TFQMR, IDR, CGNE, CGNE, LSQR, etc. etc. etc. are the usual methods of choice for such systems.

Answer (score 0):

A linear equation system $Ax=b$ with *arbritray* $A$ isn't solvable; just imagine $A_{i,j}=0$ everywhere; you will at least have to assume that the system is solvable aka that $A$ has full rank.

In this case, amongst all iterative methods, [GMRES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method) makes the least assumptions. The system doesn't have to be definite or symmetric.